# Deploying python docker images on AKS gives "exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error"

Tags: python, azure, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a docker container with a python app to Azure Kubernetes Service. After deploying and looking at the logs on the new pod, I see this error:

> exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error

I'm building the container on a mac using the following docker buildx command:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/x86_64 -t <my username>/ingest .
```

My Docker file has the following header

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 python:3.11
```

My deployment yaml looks like the following and seems to pull the image just fine.(I just used something from the azure documentation as a template.)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingest
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      bb: ingest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        bb: ingest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ingest
        image: <my username>/ingest:0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

When I inspect the images locally, I see

```
"Architecture": "amd64",
"Os": "linux",
```

I'm was assuming that the default chip architecture is x86_64, but not sure. I also built the image with default chip architecture and OS and tested locally - it works fine. I'm new to K8 and Azure. Maybe, I'm missing something obvious. Is there a way to specify the chip architecture and the OS for in my configuration? If I don't specify it, what is the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below error will come when an container is getting executed in an architecture which are not built for.

> ```
> exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error
> ```

The default value will be the value of os arch where buildkit is running.  More details how to build images for other arch is explained in [docker buildx documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#platform).

In your case you can use below which build image for arm64(mac os AArch64) and x86 arch

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64
```

Comment: --platform=linux/amd64 worked. Thanks.